# Drag and Drop from Explorer to Application on Windows Server 2012 R2 not working

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-server-2012-r2

i have a c# application where i can drag and drop files from explorer to a treeview. on our old windows server 2008 r2 everything is working fine. the application is NOT elevated!

however on the new windows server 2012 r2 the drag and drop functionality of the application is not working. same settings, the application is not elevated.
i have no clue what's the cause of this problem.

how i handle the drag and drop:

```
private void treeViewDateien_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

the DragDrop event is not fired on the new server.

thanks in advance for help!

benjey

edit:

i did some further testing. i've created a simple windows forms application with a treeview and enabled drag and drop with the same code. everything is working fine, DragDrop event gets called. so the problem should be something at the combination of my application and the new server!?

to sum it up:
Drag&Drop on main application: working on server 2008 r2, NOT working on 2012 r2.
Drag&Drop on simple test application: working on both servers.

additional information:
all the application folders and the executable is stored on the server 2012 r2. from 2008 r2 we are connecting via net drive to access the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the old Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook PIA, which is not working anymore on the new server.
changing it to the .COM reference solved it